# C++ Function call by reference

Tags: c++, reference

Why when you make the parameters of a function references in C++ the function doesn't work with the memory values of the variables?, this really is a noob question but I don't understand why when you print a reference it shows the memory value but when a function calls by reference then it works with the data that's in the reference.
Thanks in advancement!

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and show some code.

Comment: You might be confusing the address-of operator `&` (used in expressions) and the type declarator `&` which introduces reference type (used in types).

Comment: References are *aliases* for other variables. They are not very much objects themselves. When you take the address of a reference, you are *really* taking the address of the referenced variable. Also remember that C++ is a *context sensitive* language, so symbols like `&` mean *different* things in different contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases:

1. When you declare a object as a reference to a certain type, the `&` is used as part of type specifier.

```cpp
// double& is the type specifier
void func(double& value) {...}

double foo = 5;
func(foo);
```

In this example, `value` can be considered an "alias" of `foo`;

2. When you want to get the address of a object, you use `&` as [address-of operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/). `&variable_name` would give you the address of `variable_name`.